# How to create a backup of a SQL Azure DB with PITR and LTR history for Disaster Recovery?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I hope I am asking this in the correct community. I did check for SQL Azure in others, but could not find anything so here goes.

I am trying to work out the best strategy to create a backup of my SQL Azure DB if my main datacentre has a significant availability or integrity problem. My initial thought was to "Create a Database", in a different region, on a new DB Server, using the "Geo-Replicated Backup" which works excellently. However because it is on a new DB Server I lose all of my Short Term (PITR) and Long Term Retention(LTR) Backups which I might need to restore from for data correction or compliance.

So how can I backup this "history". I may have missed something simple, but my only ideas at present are:

1. Take automated "Exports" to BACPACs" to Azure Storage, say weekly.
2. Use specialised Backup software such as VEEAM SQL Azure Backup which retains multiple versions, and can operate at hourly intervals. Works off Transaction Logs.
3. Use Azure Failover groups which effectively use 2 DB Servers and 2 PITR and LTR setups.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you set up active geo-dr, the replica has a backup chain in the second region...

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT Thanks for this. Yes I can setup an active geo-dr replica. However the backups start from the date that I setup that replica. I wondered whether one could access these backups that MS automatically makes for the current DB as I believe there is a full backup each week, even though within the week, it is via Transaction Logs? As far as my understanding goes these files are hidden and only available to MS, so if I am creating a new DB from a Geo Backup in a different region, then no history. Thanks

Comment: perhaps it would help to declare your use case more fully.  If you want full history in another region, I've given you an answer that works - just keep another database running there.   PITR is not a DR solution, as such.  It is an ability to let you restore to whenever you want.  You have a cross-region DR solution without PITR-like ability - you can restore the most recent database.  Please explain why you need both (and don't want to pay for it with the solution I proposed)?